# Icon In a button -xcode view controller

Tags: iphone

i created a button where i want to place a icon/image  inside the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use custom button and use any view you want for it

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

double click on the .xib file now select the button and click
 on tools->Identity inspector there it will indicate the class is inherited from UIButton below select the image option for button ,
 Tools ->Attribute Inspector give the name for the button and also the icon name

Make sure you have included the icon in ur project

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these two methods in UIButton:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```